# Parse date to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00" using Groovy

Tags: datetime, groovy, soapui, datetime-format

I am trying to parse date format '2017-12-18T20:41:06.136Z' into "2017-12-18'T'00:00:00"

```
Date date = new Date();
def dateformat =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
dateformat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZoneCode));
def currentDate = dateformat.format(date)
log.info "Current Date : " + currentDate
date1 =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00").parse(currentDate)
log.info "Current Date : " + date1
```

Error displayed :

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2017-12-18T20:46:06:234Z" error at line: 16

This line gives error :

```
date1 =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00").parse(currentDate)
```

Comment: You running on Java 8?

Comment: @tim_yates  Yes...Is this related to java version.

Comment: @rAJ, Please see if the below solution helps to resolve the issue.

Comment: No, but Java 8 has much better date classes than Java util date

Comment: [Added a Groovy running on Java 8 version below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923883/6509)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to avoid the mentioned error, use below statement `Date.parse(..)`:

```
def dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
def dateString = "2017-12-18T20:41:06.136Z"
def date = Date.parse(dateFormat, dateString)
```

You should be able to achieve what you are trying to using below script.

```
//Change timezone if needed 
def tz = 'IST'  
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(tz))

def dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
def dateString = "2017-12-18T20:41:06.136Z"

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
calendar.with {
  time = Date.parse(dateFormat,dateString)
  set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
  set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
  set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)     
  set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
}
log.info calendar.time.format(dateFormat)
```

You can quickly try the same online <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/lP5Ux8)</kbd>

Comment: Perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: FYI: This code uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted entirely by the modern java.time classes. See [the Answer by tim _yates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923883/642706).

Answer (score 5):

Running Groovy on Java 8 gives you access to the much better Date/Time classes...  You can just do:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

String result = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-12-18T20:41:06.136Z")
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: Better to use the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class for a UTC value. Use `ZonedDateTime` for when you have a full time zone such as `Europe/Paris` or `Africa/Casablanca`.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to parse only part of date, use the following syntax:

```
Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",'2017-12-18T16:05:58bla-bla')
```